# Code for finding the number pi by the Antiphon formula

Tags: c

there is such a need that you need to find the number pi using the Antiphon formula. There is a code that defines a number and counts normally up to 24 (entered from the keyboard), but I need to use a larger limit, for example 100, 1000, 3000 and so on, here just the problem arises that numbers are first output whose first three numbers do not look like 3.14 (from the word at all), and then in all 0. Can anyone tell why this is happening and how to fix it.

```
double rec(int k, int k_max) {
    if (k > k_max) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (k == 1)
        return sqrt(2 - rec(k + 1, k_max));
    else
        return sqrt(2 + rec(k + 1, k_max));
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int t, k = 1;
    double antif, k_p;
    scanf_s("%d", &t);
    antif = pow(2, t) * rec(1, t);
    printf("%f", antif);
    return 0;
}
```

For example, I enter numbers from 4 to 24 and 3.141593 is output, but starting from 25 to 28 large numbers are output, and already from 29 0 is output

Comment: When `t` is large, there isn't enough precision in floating point to hold all the digits of `pow(2, t)`.

Comment: That is, do I need to change from double to float, or change the data type of t, which works as a limiter?

Comment: No, that's backwards. Double is larger than float. But it's still pretty limited. You need a multi-precision library, like GMP.

Comment: In my test, the output approaches *π* for `t` in the range 1..16, and from `t = 17` the output exceeds *π*.

Comment: For larger numbers your `rec()` is becoming closer and closer to zero, loosing precision: https://ideone.com/hHNqzG

Comment: ...at `t == 28` the output is `4.00000000` and thereafter it is `0`.

Comment: @Barmar "When t is large, there isn't enough precision in floating point to hold all the digits of pow(2, t)" is unclear as `pow(2, t)` is _exact_ for `t` up to about 1023.  I think you might be referring to the imprecision of other computations.

Comment: supplement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula

Comment: @Denis Vesug, when `t == 14` , the result is correct to 9 decimal digits.  Why do you want to use a limit like "100, 1000, 3000 and so on" as `double` can only represent π to about 17 digits?  A goal of `t` up the 30s is more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell why this is happening ...

Precision limitation in `double` and [catastrophic subtraction cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation).

As `k_max` grows, `rec(k + 1, k_max)` approaches 2.0 and `2 - rec(k + 1, k_max)` becomes 0.0.

---

A slight re-write of code demos this limitation.  The best π occurs when `t == 14`.  After that, the precision loss in `2 - rec(k + 1, k_max)` becomes important.

```
double rec(int k, int k_max) {
  if (k > k_max) {
    return 0;
  }
  double r = rec(k + 1, k_max);
  if (k == 1) {
    printf("%.17g: ", r);
    return sqrt(2 - r);
  } else {
    return sqrt(2 + r);
  }
}

int Antiphon(int t) {
  printf("%3d: ", t);
  double antif;
  ;
  antif = pow(2, t) * rec(1, t);
  printf("%.16f\n", antif);
  fflush(stdout);
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  for (int t = 1; t < 32; t++) {
    Antiphon(t);
  }
  printf("%20s pi: 3.1415926535897932384626433832...\n","");
}
```

Output

```
  1: 0: 2.8284271247461903
  2: 1.4142135623730951: 3.0614674589207178
  3: 1.8477590650225735: 3.1214451522580529
  4: 1.9615705608064609: 3.1365484905459406
  5: 1.9903694533443939: 3.1403311569547392
  6: 1.9975909124103448: 3.1412772509327569
  7: 1.9993976373924085: 3.1415138011441455
  8: 1.999849403678289: 3.1415729403678827
  9: 1.9999623505652022: 3.1415877252799609
 10: 1.9999905876191524: 3.1415914215046352
 11: 1.9999976469034038: 3.1415923456110768
 12: 1.9999994117257645: 3.1415925765450043
 13: 1.9999998529314358: 3.1415926334632482
 14: 1.9999999632328584: 3.1415926548075892  Best approximation of pi
 15: 1.9999999908082147: 3.1415926453212153
 16: 1.9999999977020537: 3.1415926073757197
 17: 1.9999999994255133: 3.1415929109396727
 18: 1.9999999998563782: 3.1415941251951911
 19: 1.9999999999640945: 3.1415965537048196
 20: 1.9999999999910236: 3.1415965537048196
 21: 1.9999999999977558: 3.1416742650217575
 22: 1.9999999999994389: 3.1418296818892015
 23: 1.9999999999998597: 3.1424512724941338
 24: 1.9999999999999649: 3.1424512724941338
 25: 1.9999999999999911: 3.1622776601683795
 26: 1.9999999999999978: 3.1622776601683795
 27: 1.9999999999999993: 3.4641016151377544
 28: 1.9999999999999998: 4.0000000000000000
 29: 2: 0.0000000000000000
 30: 2: 0.0000000000000000
 31: 2: 0.0000000000000000
                     pi: 3.1415926535897932384626433832...
```

---

> ... and how to fix it(?)
> I need to use a larger limit, for example 100, 1000, 3000 and so on

- Could use `long double`, but that may only provide a few more digits.
- Use a *much* wider type for the the floating point form some wide precision library.
- Use another algorithm.  Below.

---

**Alterative**

A similar algorithm that does not have the subtraction cancellation: [Viète's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula#Interpretation_and_convergence)

```
double Viete(unsigned n) {
    double a = sqrt(2.0);
    double sum = a/2;
    for (unsigned i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
      a = sqrt(2 + a);
      sum *= a/2;
    }
    return 2.0/sum;
}

int main(void) {
  for (unsigned t = 1; t < 32; t++) {
    printf("%2u %.16g\n", t, Viete(t));
  }
  printf("   %.16g\n", acos(-1));
  puts("   3.1415926535897932384626433832...");
}
```

````
 1 2.82842712474619
 2 3.061467458920718
 3 3.121445152258052
 4 3.136548490545939
 5 3.140331156954753
 6 3.141277250932773
 7 3.141513801144301
 8 3.141572940367091
 9 3.141587725277159
10 3.1415914215112
11 3.141592345570118
12 3.141592576584872
13 3.141592634338563
14 3.141592648776985
15 3.141592652386591
16 3.141592653288993
17 3.141592653514593
18 3.141592653570993
19 3.141592653585093
20 3.141592653588619
21 3.1415926535895
22 3.14159265358972
23 3.141592653589775
24 3.141592653589789
25 3.141592653589793
26 3.141592653589794
27 3.141592653589794
28 3.141592653589794
29 3.141592653589794
30 3.141592653589794
31 3.141592653589794
   3.141592653589793
   3.1415926535897932384626433832...```
````

Comment: the program works well, but I need to find the number pi through the Antiphon formula, and not through the Vieta, which is easier and there is more information on it